# Accessing hidden input elements

Tags: html, css, accessibility

**My question:**
How to access hidden input elements via tab?

**Detailed explanation:**

On my website, for radio buttons I have set visibility none and customized the before element to get a custom design.

The problem is when I try to access the input type radio via tab I am unable to do it since it is visibility hidden.

So, can anyone suggest me how to access hidden input elements with tab?

**Website**

[Demo Form](http://glamsdalen.s1.hoeks.dk/meld-dig-ind/)

Please visit the link above, you will find a form there. Now, please try to access the radio buttons with tab. It skips the radio buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have an item in your tab flow that supports `tabindex`, and since your radio button is hidden that won't work.  The **anchor tag** does support tab index however, so you can wrap the inner elements of each of your li tags with an `a` tag, and assign it a tabindex that works in your flow...

**Change:**

```
<li tabindex="0" class="radio gchoice_2_14_0">
    <input style="margin-left:1px;" name="input_14" type="radio" value="2017/2018" id="choice_2_14_0" onclick="gf_apply_rules(2,[0]);" onkeypress="gf_apply_rules(2,[0]);">
    <label tabindex="0" for="choice_2_14_0" id="label_2_14_0">2017/2018
    </label>
</li>
```

**To:**

```
<li tabindex="0" class="radio gchoice_2_14_0">
    <a tabindex="1010">
        <input style="margin-left:1px;" name="input_14" type="radio" value="2017/2018" id="choice_2_14_0" onclick="gf_apply_rules(2,[0]);" onkeypress="gf_apply_rules(2,[0]);">
        <label tabindex="0" for="choice_2_14_0" id="label_2_14_0">2017/2018
        </label>
    </a>
</li>
```

This will give the anchor tag focus when you tab to it (assuming the previous element's tabindex is '1009' or lower).

This answers your question on how to tab to it.  Now that you have that, you'll need to do a couple things:

1. Style the element's css for `form li.radio a:focus` as you see fit.
2. Set up key press events for the `a` elements so that you can actually select your fake radio button with the enter key press when it's focused.

Comment: `a` may not have `input`/`label` descendants.

Comment: Thanks Robert to make it clear that hidden elements can't be accessed with tab. Thus I added tabindex to a parent element and used some javascript.